# Grafana define Title value for chart

Tags: grafana, grafana-templating

I am trying to create a dashboard. Able to generate Bar Gauge from the Prometheus data for simple query `sum by (namespace) (kube_pod_container_status_running)`

[image]

I want to display only Namespace rather than {namespace="kube-system"}, so was playing with **Visualization > Field > Title** for a while, but was not able to figure out.

[image]

Any Idea How can just display kube-system instead of {namespace="kube-system"} and make the list in sorted order, because everytime when i refresh the dashboard, it reshuffles the order.

What I need here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/features/datasources/prometheus/

> Legend format
>
> Controls the name of the time series, using name or pattern. For example {{hostname}} will be replaced with label value for the label hostname.

=> configure `Legend format` in the `Queries` section and add `{{namespace}}` there.

I'm not sure about sort. You may try Prometheus `sort/sort_desc` function to sort query result.